# Am I voting up people's answers to my questions?

Tags: support, voting

Seems like this answer should be so obvious. I apologize, because I tried to find it.

Since I got good answers to my question, I was trying to 'vote up' the person who gave me the good scoop. There is an arrow with the number '2' by his, and another persons, answer chain. If I mouse over the up arrow, it indicates I will be toggling that off. That seems wrong.

I was able to click the check mark, to indicate that this was a good answer.

But when I check my profile, it indicates I haven't voted for anybody. I want people who help to know they are appreciated.

Will be happy to follow a link that explains what I'm not seeing. I really do try to read the Gol Durned manual.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, clicking the arrow above the answer score is how you vote up an answer.  The message "(click again to undo)" is just there to inform you that you can undo an upvote *after* you've voted (for a limited time).

Clicking the green checkmark is how you accept an answer.  Only the person who posts a question can accept an answer, so this should be reserved for the single answer that you found to help you the most.

Comment: Thanks Bill I get it now

Comment: Laurel, you'll also note the the up or down arrow will be orange instead of gray to mark it's "on".